# How to duplicate a 2sxc app?

Tags: 2sxc

I've a 2sxc app that I like. Now I want to make a copy/duplicate to experiment further with.

In the list of my apps (in Apps Management) I don't see a "make a copy" button. Am I just missing it?

I can export the complete app to an external ZIP file just fine.
But If I try to import that I get the following error:

> > Could not import the app / package: The app could not be installed because the app-folder '/Portals/3/2sxc\InciLog' already exists. Please remove or rename the folder and install the app again.

I've tried manually duplicating that directory with a new name, but the new version hasn't showed up in Apps Management yet.

Anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the folder exists on /Portals/0/2sxc
You'll see all folder present there, named after the apps.

Delete the folder InciLog (which is probably empty anyway) and you can import again.
This behaviour typically happens when you create another portal on an existing DNN host.

Cheers 
Tycho